# How to plot data in MATLAB using custom plotting routines?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

The code is as follows:

```
k=input('enter k');
i=0:1:k;
lambda=4;
cdf = exp(-lambda) .* ((lambda.^i)./ factorial(i));
plot(i,cdf);
```

When running this code, I am getting the following error:

```
Error using plot
Attempt to execute SCRIPT newplot as a function:
C:\Users\Sudhanshu ranjan\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\matlab\graphics\newplot.m

Error in Untitled (line 9)
plot(i,cdf);
```

My `mynewplot.m` file is as follows:

```
 p = [0:0.00001:1]
  a =p.* log(2.*(p))+(1-p).* log(2.*(1-p));
  plot(p,a)
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: From the error message, I'd suggest to have a look at [Scripts vs. Functions](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html) from the MathWorks Help Center. Are you redefining `plot` somewhere? The given code runs perfectly fine in my Octave 5.2.0.

Comment: @HansHirse i have given my newplot.m file  code in my post. Please check it.                                                                                                                                                                                  p

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize, that there's also an inbuilt function called [`newplot`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/newplot.html). So, rename your script (e.g. `mynewplot.m`), and your code should work.

Answer (score 3):

There's an inbuilt MATLAB function named [`newplot`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/newplot.html), which seems to be called when running a `plot` command. By defining a custom script named `newplot.m`, you're shadowing the functionality of MATLAB's `newplot`, thus the `plot` command tries to execute a FUNCTION `newplot`, but only finds your SCRIPT `newplot`.

You can resolve that issue by simply renaming your script, e.g. `mynewplot.m`.

Comment: now it is showing this error after I rename my newplot.m file to new plot graph.m:         Error using plot
Previously accessible file "C:\Users\Sudhanshu ranjan\MATLAB\R2016a\toolbox\matlab\graphics\newplot.m" is now inaccessible.

Error in Untitled (line 9)
plot(i,cdf);

Comment: Clear all caches, etc. Maybe restart MATLAB. Most likely, there's still some reference/link to your former `newplot.m`

Comment: Please help anyone. I am not able to resolve my issue. Still after renaming my file to mynewplot.m  . The error shows that it is  inaccessible.

Comment: But why it search for that newplot.m file?  I am using only plot function in my code.

Comment: As written in my answer, it seems, that MATLAB's inbuilt `newplot` function is implicitly called, when a `plot` command is executed. Have you restarted MATLAB? Have you cleared all caches? If necessary, further edit your question and provide more details. What's `Untitled`? The script you're trying to start, I guess. Where is your `mynewplot.m` (formerly your `newplot.m`) used? You have to narrow down the possible error causes, since people here don't have access to your environment.

Comment: I already provided in my post what my newplot.m (former name) consists of. I have restarted Matlab. Untitled is my MatLab code file name.  Even I also don't know why mynewplot.m used for my simple code, even though I have not used this word anywhere in my code.

Comment: It still remains unclear, why you have/had a script `newplot.m` (former name) at all, if it's not used in the provided context. Is that from a different project? What happens, when you start a fresh MATLAB and just try to `plot(1:10)`? Does the error also occur? Have a look at [`which`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) and [`rehash`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rehash.html). Did you maybe overwrite the original MATLAB `newplot.m` (if that file is accessible at all)?

Comment: @HansHire Even I don't know my simple code looks for newplot.m file? on plotting(1,10) gives the same error. This problem only occurs when I used plot function in my code.  Does the plot function has some relation with newplot.m?

Comment: As already mentions twice: YES - it seems, when you use `plot`, that internally several commands are processed, and one of them is `newplot`. From your observation, that also a simple `plot(1:10)` fails, it's obvious, that the original `newplot` functionality is still shadowed. Next to the hints already given, I can't further help you to investigate this issue.

Comment: sir, I tried my best to debug this error, but unable to do so. Can anyone please help.